# How to replace the Android camera emulation with a video file?

Tags: android, eclipse, video, android-emulator, camera

It is possible to replace [this emulation](http://www.tomgibara.com/images/android-camera-genuine.png) with a personal video I record ? For example a .mp4 file I captured with a Galaxy S3.

It is possible in eclipse emulator, [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture) or an other emulator/VM ?

I need this because I have to make some identical tests in an application using the camera. But I can't handle the source because I use a SDK called [Metaio](http://metaio.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emulator uses attached camera to emulate the device camera, so, you can use a fake webcam program with allow you to select the video source, try search for "fake webcam software"

Comment: It works ! Metaio + Genymotion + ManyCam (but my computer is not powerfull enough...).